# Should [toys] be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [toys](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) tag has 10 questions.  To me, this doesn't seem like an appropriate tag for the site.  A "toy" can be anything used in play; any size, any material, suitable for any age, etc.  Tagging a question with [toys](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) provides no information specific to a characteristic or requirement that's relevant to the site.  Should we delete this tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, it should be removed.

A 'toy' - in the context of this website - is just another type of object made of particular materials, and **the *materials* (and mechanisms/techniques) are pertinent to the question and answer, not the fact that they constitute a toy**.

***But* the tag does provide some information, as it emphasizes that potential solutions should be safe for children** (although as it is currently used that restriction doesn't always apply).
I suggest adding a [child-safe](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-safe) tag instead, as a more specialized version of [safety](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety), or change the latter to represent a potential answer should take child safety into consideration.
But, again, this is not specific to toys, and if that is the only information it provides, it is better to exchange [toys](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) with a more meaningful tag like [child-safe](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-safe).

Comment: I expanded the [safety] wiki to make child-safe an explicit component.  If you think it would be helpful to have a [child-safe] tag, we could create it and synonymize it with [safety].

Comment: Adding the intended use in the question should be enough, making “toy” unnecessary.

Comment: I also think that there’s a difference between child-safe and safety: the ways things can be dangerous to children is way greater than for adults. A sharp edge is dangerous for all ages, but adults don’t tend to put as many things in their mouth or choke on small pieces as toddlers do. Remember that small children do tend to explore their world by putting objects into their mouths.

Comment: Yes, +1 to have an additional [child-safe] tag, also because its use might be a little more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close the loop on this question, the [toys](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) tag has been cleared.