# Are there enough questions to warrant a "stuffed-animal" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a question about repairing a stuffed animal, and after looking around the Arts & Crafts website, I saw there were other repair/creation questions regarding stuffed animals as well.

Does it make sense to create a stuffed animal tag? Or is simply having all the individual tags that make up a stuffed animal (examples, "painting", "sewing", "stuffing") enough?

I don't know what "popularity" is required for a new tag. For example, I saw that the tag  [doll-reborning](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doll-reborning) only has two questions on the main site, but I'm sure it is helpful for the users who participate in this craft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[stuffed-animal](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stuffed-animal) probably isn't a great tag.  It's not a matter of whether there are enough questions, it's that it doesn't focus on something that serves a tag purpose on the site.  It's about how the item will be used rather than the Arts & Crafts function seeking a solution.  This is similar to the [toys](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) tag that was discussed in the Meta post [Should [toys] be removed?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/8251)

Any question will be about some specific aspect, like sewing, stuffing, repairing the eyes, material selection, etc.  Those are site topics and relevant tags.  One could even add a tag for child-safe if that tag has been created, or safety (which currently includes it).

Tagging that an item is or will become a stuffed animal doesn't help to attract the right people to answer the technical question, or search for a solution.  There's nothing wrong, though with mentioning that the item is a stuffed animal in the question's title or body because that provides context.

Comment: That's a good perspective. Then, following that logic, should [tag:doll-reborning] be removed? Because that can also be broken down into various aspects such as vinyl painting, dying vinyl/plastic, molding for shaping etc. And I assume someone could find the questions because the asker mentioned "doll-reborning" in the body of the question.

Comment: @Wimateeka, I wasn't even aware that doll reborning was a thing.  :-)  From the tag wiki, that sounds like a specific, defined process, with experts who focus on that, which might warrant a dedicated tag.  But I'm not familiar enough with it to have an opinion.  BTW, "CATaracts": excellent!

Comment: I wasn't either familiar with doll-reborning either until I was looking to see if any toy related tags existed, and that's the only one I could find. I had no idea what it was and had to look up its definition on wikipedia. Thanks for the feedback! I'll mark the question as answered :D